# Android quiz app crashing

Tags: java, android

I developing a simple quiz app and I'm having a problem I think with the codes. It crashes when I click the submit button if the text fields are left blank. Here's my code.

```
public class Quiz extends Activity
{

Button submit;
EditText e1,e2,e3,e4,e5;
int ctr;
String msg = "", msg1 = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);
    submit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    e1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    e2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    e3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    e4=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    e5=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText5);
    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

          @Override
          public void onClick(View arg0){
              String ans1 = String.valueOf(e1.getText());
              int ans11 = Integer.parseInt(ans1);
              String ans2 = String.valueOf(e2.getText());
              int ans22 = Integer.parseInt(ans2);
              String ans3 = String.valueOf(e3.getText());
              int ans33 = Integer.parseInt(ans3);
              String ans4 = String.valueOf(e4.getText());
              int ans44 = Integer.parseInt(ans4);
              String ans5 = String.valueOf(e5.getText());
              int ans55 = Integer.parseInt(ans5);

              if(e1.getText().toString().equals("")||e2.getText().toString().equals("")||e3.getText().toString().equals("")||e4.getText().toString().equals("")||e5.getText().toString().equals("")){
                    msg1 = "Text fields cannot be empty.";
                     Toast.makeText(Quiz.this, msg1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
                  }

              else{
              if(ans11==4){
                  ctr++;
              }
              if(ans22==3){
                  ctr++;
              }
              if(ans33==1){
                  ctr++;
              }
              if(ans44==2){
                  ctr++;
              }
              if(ans55==5){
                  ctr++;
              }
              msg = "Your score is " + ctr;
                 Toast.makeText(Quiz.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              }


          }
      });
}
```

The logcat says:

```
10-06 21:47:35.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1759): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-06 21:47:35.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1759): java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '' as integer
10-06 21:47:35.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1759):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:362)
10-06 21:47:35.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1759):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
10-06 21:47:35.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1759):     at com.example.capslock.Quiz$1.onClick(Quiz.java:39)
10-06 21:47:35.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1759):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
10-06 21:47:35.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1759):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
10-06 21:47:35.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1759):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
10-06 21:47:35.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1759):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-06 21:47:35.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1759):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
10-06 21:47:35.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1759):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
10-06 21:47:35.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1759):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-06 21:47:35.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1759):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-06 21:47:35.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1759):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
10-06 21:47:35.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1759):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
10-06 21:47:35.888: E/AndroidRuntime(1759):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What says the LogCoat?

Comment: Yeah what does LogCat say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to get your String from an editText with

```
editText.getText().toString();
```

if you want to compare a string with another String make this:

```
if(ans1.equals("4")){...}
```

If you want a Integer from a EditText try this

```
int a11 = 0;
try {
  a11 = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());
}catch(NumberFormatException e){   }
```

So you do not get a Exception, when there is no String or a litteral String in your EditText

I was right, that you tried to parse an Integer from "" :-D

Comment: Knowningly causing and catching an exception should be avoided whenever possible because it is such an expensive operation.  Far better here to say `String value = editText.getText().toString();if(editText!=null & editText.length>0){a11 = Integer.parseInt(value);}`